# Error compiling bc: cannot find libreadline.so.8

Tags: compiling, shared-library, lfs, bc

I am following the Linux from Scratch book, Version 8.4 and am stuck on compiling bc ([Chapter 6.15](http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/bc.html)).

I have copied and pasted the commands on that page up to the make command, but when I run make, I get this error:

```
./fbc -c ./libmath.b </dev/null >libmath.h
./fbc: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [Makefile:631: libmath.h] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/sources/bc-1.07.1/bc'
```

I have checked inside /lib and /usr/lib for libreadline.so.8 and it is present in both directories. I have also tried copying libreadline.so.8 to /sources/bc-1.07.1/bc, /sources/bc-1.07.1/bc/lib, and /sources/bc-1.07.1/bc/bc, but I still get the same error.

Output of `cat config.log | grep readline`:

```
  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-readline --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info
configure:5164: checking for readline in -lreadline
configure:5189: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   -lncurses conftest.c -lreadline   >&5
configure:5201: checking readline/readline.h usability
configure:5201: checking readline/readline.h presence
configure:5201: checking for readline/readline.h
ac_cv_header_readline_readline_h=yes
ac_cv_lib_readline_readline=yes
READLINELIB='-lreadline -lncurses'
```

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Edit:

I managed to solve this issue by running the configure script outside of the chroot environment. The make command and tests return no errors, however I am not sure if this will break anything else in the book.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you did it e.g. which options you gave the `chroot` ? `readline` is notorious for its ability of not being found by other prgrams using it. In particular, when more than one version of `readline` is installed on the same system, it gives those kinds of errors.

Comment: To enter the chroot environment, I used `chroot "$LFS" /tools/bin/env -i HOME=/root TERM="$TERM" PS1='(lfs chroot) \u:\w\$ ' PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin /tools/bin/bash --login +h` where $LFS is equal to /mnt/lfs

Comment: This issue should also be resolved in the latest release of Linux from Scratch; the book switched to using a `bc` implementation that is easier to build.